# Difference between two arrays of objects coffeescript using underscore js

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, underscore.js, lodash

I am trying to find the difference betweeen two arrays of objects using underscore js library.

Comment: underscore in coffeescript, every sain developers nightmare, so I guess simple plain old javascript, like [**this one**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6715641/an-efficient-way-to-get-the-difference-between-two-arrays-of-objects) is out ?

Comment: Can you help me convert that to coffeescript?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Do you want to use the difference function of underscore? You can do this:

```
_.difference([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [5, 2, 10])
```

this works in coffeescript.

**EDIT**

Using an array of objects and comparing the id property

```
arrayOne = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}]
arrayTwo =[{id: 2}, {id: 3}]

_.select arrayOne, (item) ->
    !_.findWhere(arrayTwo, {id: item.id})
```

Comment: ya thats what i want to do but i want to do it for two arrays of objects not integers. Each object has a unique integer ID

Comment: Just beware: the order of the arrays matters when using _.difference(). It doesn't show you the items that don't belong to both, it shows you what you have left when you subtract the second array from the first.

Comment: Awesome elegant solution. UnderscoreJS really rocks =]