# Converting Firebase $asArray() to Javascript Array

Tags: javascript, firebase, angularfire

Is there any elegant way to go from Firebase $asArray() to a regular Javascript Array? I'm looking to get the difference between the array returned from Firebase and a regular array of objects.

```
var purchased = $firebase(new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL + 'purchased/' + uid)).$asArray();
  purchased.$loaded(function () {
    $scope.shopping_items = $(items).not(purchased).get();
  }
```

The goal of the above piece of code is to get the list of items that hasn't been purchased, the list of items is just a javascript array. If I can get the purchased array to be in the same format, the code should work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [An efficient way to get the difference between two arrays of objects?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6715641/an-efficient-way-to-get-the-difference-between-two-arrays-of-objects)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing to understand about comparing objects is that two objects with identical keys and values are not equal because they are not the same object.

```
var x = {foo: 'bar'};
var y = {foo: 'bar'};
console.log(x === y); // false
```

Keep this in mind when you are trying to compare two arrays of objects.

With that said, a Firebase array is just like a regular Javascript array except for some utility methods like $add, $remove, $save.

If you wanted to get create a copy of the firebase array without the utility methods, you could use something like the following.

```
var regularArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < firebaseArray.length; i++) {
  regularArray.push(firebaseArray[i]);
}
```

However, this doesn't doesn't really get you much closer to computing the difference of two arrays. The following  might help though.

[An efficient way to get the difference between two arrays of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6715641/an-efficient-way-to-get-the-difference-between-two-arrays-of-objects)

Comment: The link to the other question was very helpful and helped me solve the problem. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer. Any chance I could get an upvote too? It would push me over the 50 point threshold. =)